# Smart GWT Customize calendar

Tags: gwt, calendar, widget, customization, smartgwt

I'm doing some school schedule view in my app, so I thought I can use the gwt calendar widget and customize it(Add professor, some class info etc.).
For exemple like this http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#custom_editing_calendar_category

But how can I use DataSource for the additional fields?
**calendar.setEventEditorFields** - does not accept DataSource

Also If you know some better widget for this goal it will be nice to tell me more about it.

The exemple is from smartgwt showcase with the difference that I try to extend CalendarEvent so I can have for exemple new field "professor"

Thats the plase where we try to construct the calendar and trying to add an new field in the datasource.

```
    package GwtApp.TechnicalUniversityApp.client.Schedule.Vertical;

import com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource;
import com.smartgwt.client.data.fields.DataSourceDateTimeField;
import com.smartgwt.client.data.fields.DataSourceSequenceField;
import com.smartgwt.client.data.fields.DataSourceTextField;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.calendar.Calendar;

public class ScheduleLayoutVertical {

    public static Canvas buildScheduleLayout(){
        DataSource eventDS = new DataSource();  
        DataSourceSequenceField eventIdField = new DataSourceSequenceField("eventId");  
        eventIdField.setPrimaryKey(true);  

        DataSourceTextField nameField = new DataSourceTextField("name");
        DataSourceTextField descField = new DataSourceTextField("description");  
        DataSourceDateTimeField startDateField = new DataSourceDateTimeField("startDate");  
        DataSourceDateTimeField endDateField = new DataSourceDateTimeField("endDate");  
        DataSourceTextField professorField = new DataSourceTextField("professor");

        eventDS.setFields(eventIdField, nameField, descField, startDateField, endDateField,professorField);  
        eventDS.setClientOnly(true);  

        eventDS.setTestData(CalendarData.getRecords());  

        Calendar calendar = new Calendar();  
        calendar.setDataSource(eventDS);  
        calendar.setAutoFetchData(true);  


        return calendar;  
    }
}
```

Thats the plase where we populate the data and use the extended CalendarEvent

```
    package GwtApp.TechnicalUniversityApp.client.Schedule.Vertical;

import java.util.Date;

public class CalendarData {
    private static CalendarEvent[] records;  
    private static Date today = new Date();  
    private static int year = today.getYear();  
    private static int month = today.getMonth();  
    private static int start = today.getDate() - today.getDay();  

    public static CalendarEvent[] getRecords() {  
        if (records == null) {  
            records = getNewRecords();  
        }  
        return records;  
    }  

    public static CalendarEvent[] getNewRecords() {  
        return new CalendarEvent[]{  
                new CalendarEvent(1, "Meeting", "Shareholders meeting: monthly forecast report", new Date(year, month, start + 2, 9, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 2, 14, 0, 0),"TestProff1"),  
                new CalendarEvent(2, "Realtor", "Breakfast with realtor to discuss moving plans", new Date(year, month, start + 3, 8, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 3, 10, 0, 0),"TestProff2"),  
                new CalendarEvent(3, "Soccer", "Little league soccer finals", new Date(year, month, start + 4, 13, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 4, 16, 0, 0),"TestProff1"),  
                new CalendarEvent(4, "Sleep", "Catch up on sleep", new Date(year, month, start + 4, 5, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 4, 9, 0, 0),"TestProff2"),  
                new CalendarEvent(5, "Inspection", "Home inspector coming", new Date(year, month, start + 4, 10, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 4, 12, 0, 0), false, "testStyle"),  
                new CalendarEvent(6, "Airport run", "Pick James up from the airport", new Date(year, month, start + 4, 1, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 4, 3, 0, 0),"TestProff1"),  
                new CalendarEvent(7, "Dinner Party", "Prepare elaborate meal for friends", new Date(year, month, start + 4, 17, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 4, 20, 0, 0),"TestProff1"),  
                new CalendarEvent(8, "Poker", "Poker at Steve's house", new Date(year, month, start + 4, 21, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 4, 23, 0, 0),"TestProff2"),  
                new CalendarEvent(9, "Meeting", "Board of directors meeting: discussion of next months strategy", new Date(year, month, start + 5, 11, 0, 0), new Date(year, month, start + 5, 15, 0, 0),"TestProff1")  
        };  
    }  
}
```

Extended CalendarEvent with new constructor

```
package GwtApp.TechnicalUniversityApp.client.Schedule.Vertical;
```

import java.util.Date;

public class CalendarEvent extends com.smartgwt.client.widgets.calendar.CalendarEvent{

```
String professor;

public CalendarEvent(int i, String string, String string2, Date date,
        Date date2, String string3) {
    super(i, string, string2, date, date2);
    setProfessor(string3);
}



public CalendarEvent(int i, String string, String string2, Date date,
        Date date2, boolean b, String string3) {
    super(i, string, string2, date, date2, b);
    setProfessor(string3);
}



public String getProfessor() {
    return getAttributeAsString("professor");
}

public void setProfessor(String professor) {
    setAttribute("professor", professor);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The additional (custom) fields must belong to the Calendar DataSource.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I've try exactly that (new post source edit) but I cannot find a way to visualize the new field.